# Dockerized Angular/nginx project shows 403 Forbidden Win 11

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, web, frontend

I'm new with Angular and I wanted to dockerize my project. The problem that I had, occurred when I `docker compose up` and then it showed this error.

I know it has to do with the configuration of NGINX, but I'd love someone to help me.

Also, this is the error that shows

```
 2022/03/23 03:41:33 [error] 33#33: *1 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden, client: 172.26.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost:8080"
```

**dockercompose.yaml**

```
version: "3.8" services:   nginx:     build:        context: ./       dockerfile: Dockerfile     container_name: angular-app     restart: always     ports:       - "8080:80"     volumes:       - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html volumes:   html: {}
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM node:16.14.2 as node

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build --prod

FROM nginx:alpine

COPY --from=node /app/dist/angular-app /usr/share/nginx/html

EXPOSE 8080:80
```

**App component**

```
<form>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
    <div id="emailHelp" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1">
  </div>
  <div class="mb-3 form-check">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Are you sure the directory, you're trying to access, namely ~~/nginx/html is public for read? If not, you would have to add the chmod command and change permissions to be accessed publicly to that directory.

Comment: @Aryan3212 I already tried "RUN chmod -R 755 /usr/share/nginx/html" but im keeping getting the same error "*1 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden"

Comment: Did you try the stuff given in this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64440577/1-directory-index-of-usr-share-nginx-html-is-forbidden-in-mac-catalina-os

Comment: You should accept @Aryan3212 comment as the answer.